# One month rails snag when trying to deploy demo app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm a newbie trying to learn ruby on rails. I'm following the One Month Rails course and I'm currently stuck on getting my app to display on Heroku. The demo displays locally when I type localhost:3000, but when I try to deploy to app on Heroku it gives me a screen that says **"The page you were looking for doesn't exist. You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved."**

My gem file looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

group :production do
gem 'pg'
end

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'


gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


gem 'jquery-rails'


gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'heroku'




group :doc do

gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

I looked around and tried various solutions and none of them worked for this.

routes.rb file:

```
Omrails::Application.routes.draw do

get "pages/index"
root  'pages#home'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you didn't root a page yet.

You have to root as page for heroku to land there.

Put this in

```
  root 'pages#index'
```

That should work

Hope it helps

And take out

```
 get 'pages...'
 root 'pages#home'
```

Comment: I hope this isn't a dumb question, but what exactly does controller name and view name mean?

Comment: I'm also still getting the "The page you were looking for doesn't exist." page.

Comment: I took out "get 'pages...' " and tried root 'pages#home' and still got the same message.

Comment: You didn't change 'home ' to 'index'  and I just looked at the repo on git hub and it did not change so make sure you go through the process of repushing to git hub again before pushing to heroku

Comment: I'm fairly certain I did [link](https://github.com/darthredskin/omrails/blob/master/config/routes.rb)

Comment: Ahh okay. So now the "page cannot be found" message is gone. That's promising. Now it gives me a **Pages#index Find me in app/views/pages/index.html.erb** message.

Comment: That means it is working. You will add stuff onto that page as you work through the tutorial that will change what is displayed.  One tip, with the errors you are likely to encounter when you are first starting out you will get the best results by just googleing the error message exactly, most likely someone else has had the same problem (this heroku question is asked a bunch here). You can accept the answer to so it does not show up as unanswered.